# Spring security check the user is logged or not when click a button

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm creating a simple web application for online flight reservation system using Spring MVC with Spring security. I've created following table to show flight details.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Flight No</th>
            <th>Flight destination</th>
            <th>Flight origin</th>
            <th>Flight date</th>
            <th>Flight time</th>
            <th>Book now</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form:form commandName="reserv" cssClass="form-horizontal">
            <c:forEach items="${flightInfos}" var="flightInfo">
                <tr>
                    <td>${flightInfo.flightNo}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.destination}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.origin}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.flightDate}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.flightTime}</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Book now" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this table, I want to check the user is logged or not when user click on "Book now" button. It means everyone can see this page but they need to log into the system to book a flight. Here is my security.xml file.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/account**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/reservation**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

How can I check whether the user is logged or not, when he clicks on "Book now" button ? Is there any simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How can I check whether the user is logged or not, when he clicks on "Book now" button ? Is there any simple way to do this ?"

When the submit button is pressed; the form will be posted to the URL you have given it (as a POST) example:

```
<form action="/myURL" method="POST">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

just change the URL to something that is restricted in your security xml.
something like:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/postformURL" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

Then when it get your Controller mapping of the formURL ; it will only get there if it passed spring security.